# AppArmor prevents Inkscape from opening files using "Open with"

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, apparmor, inkscape

I've got Inkscape 1.2 (snap) installed on Kubuntu 22.04.

When I try to open an SVG file using the "Open with" context menu (or just double clicking the file), nothing happens, and in the syslog I find this error:

```
Jun 26 13:15:37 silverstream kernel: [ 7932.918574] audit: type=1400 audit(1656242137.513:219): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.inkscape.inkscape" name="/home/sebastian/Documents/" pid=11496 comm="head" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

I've looked in /etc/apparmor.d but can't find any profile for Inkscape there.

Even stranger, I can open the SVG file just fine if I open it from inside Inkscape (File->open).

I tried removing and reinstalling Inkscape. Didn't help.

Comment: Some suggestions in https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-open-files-in-kde-snaps/10857/7. If those don't work, then please file a bug report.

Comment: @user535733 That link appears to talk about the open file dialog (file->open) which works fine in my case.